# Beginning Javascript: How to run multiple functions in javascript block

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, qunit

I have the following block of code:

```
(function() {
    QUnit.config.testTimeout = 10000;

    var stringformat = QUnit.stringformat;

    module('Web API GET Result has expected shape');



    asyncTest('HomeData should return an array of Sets with their info as well as cards with their info, but no sides',        
        function () {
            $.ajax({
                    url: '/sample/url',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (result) {
                        ok(
                            !!result.item, 'Got something');
                        start();
                    },
                    error: function(result) {
                        ok(false, 'Failed with: ' + result.responseText);
                        start();
                    }
                }

            );
        }
        );

    return function () { asyncTest(); };

    }
```

I'm trying to run this for multiple URLs with different results, but I can't figure out how to run asyncTest twice with different parameters.  I tried assigning the function (second parameter of asyncTest) to a variable and inserting it into asyncTest() however this doesn't work.  How can I define multiple "asyncTest"s and run them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.deferred(), $.when() and $.pipe() are your friends if you use jQuery [apparent from the code].
Good tutorials on the above are [here](http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/), [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/wrangle-async-tasks-with-jquery-promises/)